# Using UPDATE query to copy data from a lookup table into the main table

Tags: mysql, sql

I made a booboo.

In my main table, I stored the primary key of the data from the lookup table, rather than the data itself. The table is called Country and I'm displaying CountryID instead of CountryName.

Now my maintable has lots of 1s and 2s and 3s alongside each entry instead of USA, England, France etc.

What kind of UPDATE query do I need that will copy over the relevant data from each entry, so that if Maintable.Country = 1, it will copy over the CountryName associated with CountryID = 1?

Comment: You did the right thing.  Now use a `JOIN` to get the name of the country.

Comment: For normalization purposes, you typically want to store the key in the child table rather than the data (what you did), then query against the Country table for the rest of the data. If you do want the data in the other table instead, it would be easier to help if we saw your table structure.